# hash_map< vector<int>, int> error when using find function

Tags: c++, vector, find, hashmap

```
struct HASH_CMP {
    bool operator()(vector<int> V, vector<int> W) const {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            if(V[i] != W[i]) return false;
        return true;
    }
};
hash_map< std::vector<int>, int, HASH_CMP > H;

long long inHash(const vector<int> &V) {
    if(H.find(V) == H.end()) return -1; //this line
    return H[V];
}
```

I have declared the following hash, given the comparing class above and I receive an error at the line mentioned saying:

> no match for call to '`(const HASH_CMP) (const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)`

I need some help on fixing this code.

Comment: You never wrote a [hashing function](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/HashFunction.html) (returns a `size_t`). You can only put something in a hash map if you have a way to hash it.

Comment: I believe you want to accept your vectors by reference to `const` in `operator ()`

Comment: BTW there is an equality comparison `operator==` for `std::vector`. It doesn't do exactly the same as yours, but it might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The third template argument is the hash functor. The comparison functor is the *fourth* template argument. Thus you need:

```
hash_map<std::vector<int>, int, HASH_HASH, HASH_CMP>
```

And you still need to write `HASH_HASH`.

(I recommend you look at Boost's [`hash_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html) implementation for inspiration.) Also note that equality for vectors is already defined (and more efficiently than your version) and shouldn't require self-written code.

Answer (score 1):

As the error is telling you, you need a hashing function that takes a `const std::vector<int>&` and returns a `size_t`. To put something in a hash map, there has to be some way to hash it.

This will work:

```
size_t operator()(const vector<int>& vec)
{
    size_t v = 0;
    for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
        v = (v ^ *it) * 0x9e3779b9;
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Considering I am creating a function which returns a size_t, how will hash_map deal with collisions?

Comment: It will put collisions in the same bucket and have to compare things element-by-element.